# Position checkbox to topright corner

Tags: android

I want to create a checkbox to choose colour in my android app. The checkbox however appears at the leftmost center. How to position it at the top right corner?
[This is how I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkbXr.png)

Comment: Post the code you tried

Comment: Which layout r u using,post the layout file so we can have a look

Comment: I'm using tablerow for having 4 checkboxes. The checkboxes are created properly. But the tiny box that actually gets checked comes at the left center. Instead I need at the top right corner as it usually comes when we select image from gallery.

Comment: put the layout_gravity attribute of the ceckbox to top|left

Comment: I've tried that. Top works fine. But right isn't.

Comment: <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/red_button"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/red1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:checked="false"
            android:gravity="top" />

Comment: what is the parent layout that your checkbox is contained in

Comment: is it linear or ralative

Comment: TableRow layout..and it's linear.

Comment: then have you tried using parent align attribute

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">
     <CheckBox 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="@drawable/red_button"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:id="@+id/red1"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
         android:checked="false"
         android:gravity="right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps!!!